# How can I tell if Windows 8 users have a tablet or PC

Tags: google-analytics, windows-8

We have had some complaints from users who are using Windows 8. I'd like to use Google Analytics to review the behavior of users depending on whether they are using Windows 8 on a tablet or Windows 8 on a PC.

How can I tell them apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***How can I tell if Windows 8 users have a tablet or PC?***

Google Analytics has a filter for [Tablet](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034380?hl=en) (click "Mobile Device" and look at the second row), which will help determine whether Windows 8 users are using a tablet or PC.

To compare these two segments, go to:

> Standard Reports -> Audience -> Mobile -> Devices

Then:

1.) Click the down arrow just above the `Explorer` tab

2.) Click the `Create New Segment` button

3.) Click `Technology`

4.) For `Operating System` select `Windows`

5.) For `Operating System Version` select `8`

6.) Scroll down to `Mobile (Including Tablet)` and check `No`

7.) Specify the segment name at the top (above `Demographics`) as "Windows 8 Desktop Users" and click `Save`.

Next, to view Windows 8 tablet users:

8.) Repeat steps 1-6, but check `Yes` in step 6.

9.) Then under `Advanced -> Conditions`, click on the `Ad Content` button and select: `Visitors -> Tablet` and chose `Yes`.

10.) Specify the segment name as "Windows 8 Tablet Users" and click `Save`.

While viewing these segments, you can can click the `Add to Dashboard` button to add them to your Dashboard for quicker access.

--

Side note: For Internet Explorer user-agents for tablets, you should likely include those for [ARM-based Windows RT models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#architecture) too, which do not contain the string "Touch" in them, but are touch-enabled. Also "Touch" can apply to all-in-one PC's that are touch-enabled too (not just tablets).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to filter out the traffic source by filtering through using the user agent.

[Desktops and Laptops will use any of the following:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **32-bit Internet Explorer 10 on 32-bit Windows 8:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
>
> **32-bit Internet Explorer 10 on 64-bit Windows 8:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64;
>   Trident/6.0)
>
> **64-bit Internet Explorer 10 on 64-bit Windows 8:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64;
>   Trident/6.0)

While the Tablets will use something like this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; Touch)`

The important thing to notice with the above user agent is the `Touch` and `Windows NT 6.2` as Windows NT 6.2 is Windows8 and anything with Touch on the end is to indicate a touch screen device that would mean a mobile or tablet. But other than that there's no other way of finding out other than that which I've stated.

Comment: I'm feeling stupid, but I can't find where I sort results by user agent..