# How can I get a breakdown of Windows 32 bit vs Windows 64 bit visitors in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, windows

I am trying to find out how many of my website conversions are from users running on 32 bit or 64 bit Windows operating systems. I can't seem to find this in GA no matter how far I drill down.
I can get down to Windows users running 7, 8, 10 etc, but not further than that.
Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

The [UserAgent Explanation here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52885/53458) should be what you're looking for.

---

You should be able to filter out the traffic source by filtering through using the user agent.

[Desktops and Laptops will use any of the following:](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52885/53458)

> **32-bit Internet Explorer 10 on 32-bit Windows 8:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
>
> **32-bit Internet Explorer 10 on 64-bit Windows 8:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64;
> Trident/6.0)
>
> **64-bit Internet Explorer 10 on 64-bit Windows 8:**
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64;
> Trident/6.0)

---

Of course that appears to be specific to Internet Explorer

---

Did some more digging and found instructions on how to use the UA in GA

> In the Admin section of your Google Analytics account for the property you are looking to track select Custom Definitions. From there we are going to set up a Custom Dimension to enable a Secondary Dimension for reporting within Analytics Reporting section.
>
> Create a Custom Dimension, name it User Agent with a Scope of Hit and tick the Active checkbox.
>
> Google Analytics Custom Dimension to track 32 or 64 bit operating systems
>
> Add the following to your Analytics tracking code

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', escape(navigator.userAgent));
```

[Source](https://www.stevensoehl.com/google-analytics-custom-dimensions-track-browser-bit/)